# Javascript/html, can't write twice in a input

Tags: javascript, input

I'm doing a schoolproject, trying to do an list of things you need to buy. 
The problem is, i can't write more than one time and add to the list, and i can't figure out why. 
(It's nowhere near done.) (i have to diffrent javascript files)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Inköpslista</title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="kol1" class="kol">
<h1>Inköp</h1>
<input type="image" src="img/button.png" alt="Submit" id="storknapp"         onclick="klickaKnapp('skriva')"/>
 <input type"text" id="skriva" placeholder="Skriv din vara här!"/>
 <input type="image" id="knapp" src="pluss.png" alt="Submit"/>


</div>

<div id="kol2">
<ul id="listaavvara"></ul>
</div>

<script src="menudropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>

</body>
</html>



function laggtill(cool, namnVara) {
var vara = document.createElement("li");
vara.innerText = namnVara;

cool.appendChild(vara);
}

var button = document.getElementById("knapp");
button.onclick = function() { 

    var skriva = document.getElementById("skriva")
    var namnVara = skriva.value;

    if(!namnVara|| namnVara =="" || namnVara == " " ){
        return false; 

    }

    laggtill(document.getElementById("listaavvara"), namnVara); 

};
```

javascrpit 2:

```
function klickaKnapp(x){
var skrivrutan = document.getElementById(x), maxH="100px";


if(skrivrutan.style.height == maxH){
    skrivrutan.style.height = "0px";

} else {
    skrivrutan.style.height = maxH;

}
}
```

HOPEFULLY YOU KNOW WHAT I MEAN! (my pictures are not here)

Comment: And what errors appear in your JavaScript console when you run that code, or try to use it 'more than one time'?

Comment: there are no errors!

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
var button = document.getElementById("knapp");
button.onclick = function() { ... }
```

overrides the inline event handler. You need to attach events with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(){...}, false);
```

Comment: i don't know if i did something wrong, but for me it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zjb86ab/

So this looks like there is something wrong with your imported scripts

```
<script src="menudropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>
```

Are those the two files with your javascript snippets inside?

You could also try to replace

```
var button = document.getElementById("knapp");
button.onclick = function() {
```

with

```
function addItem() {
```

and then add the function as onclick attribute like you do with the klickaKnapp function

```
<input type="image" id="knapp" src="pluss.png" alt="Submit" onclick="addItem()" />
```

Comment: hm, maybe i did something wrong then! 

No they are in two diffrent files :) the first in java.js and the second one in menudropdown.js, everything else works except from that i can't get more than one item in the list.

Comment: hm how about you try to debug your code? You could check, whether the laggtill function gets called each time you click the button.

Comment: oh well, glad you found the problem :)